# COM visible DLL only registered for Administrators

Tags: windows, uac, com

I have a 64-bit DLL and I also have an installer for this dll. This installer registers the dll as com visible. To do this i have to be admin. Everything works fine so far and i also can use the dll (it's a SolidWorks Plugin). I can also change the user and login with another administrator account and it still works, but when i login with a windows standard user - the dll is suddenly not registered anymore (although it says in the registry).

How can i register the ComDLL for everyone including standard users?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit (Professional and Ultimate - same result)

Comment: That is to be expected the different flavors of a specific version of Windows are identical when it comes to something like this.  Can you provide the exact command you are using to registered the dll?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665772/how-to-register-a-com-object-for-all-users) is an explanation.  You are already doing it the correct way.  So that leaves either a specific configuration problem which will require some more work on your part or a problem with the dll.